# Why am i getting ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)?

Tags: python-3.x

my df 'td'is a time series data with months for index and one column for performance value ranging between 0-1. i'm trying to run a stationarity-test

'''

```
def stationarity_test(timeseries):
    """"Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test
    Test for Stationarity"""
    from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
    print("Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:")
    df_test = adfuller(timeseries, autolag = "AIC")
    df_output = pd.Series(df_test[0:4],
                          index = ["Test Statistic", "p-value", "#Lags Used",
                                   "Number of Observations Used"])
    print(df_output)
stationarity_test(td)
```

'''

error received:
Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-143-69a68080d36a>", line 12, in <module>
    stationarity_test(td)

  File "<ipython-input-143-69a68080d36a>", line 6, in stationarity_test
    df_test = adfuller(timeseries, autolag = "AIC")

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\stattools.py", line 221, in adfuller
    xdall = lagmat(xdiff[:, None], maxlag, trim='both', original='in')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\tsatools.py", line 397, in lagmat
    nobs, nvar = xa.shape

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```